# kube-prometheus-stack. Why doesn't Prometheus see external node-exporters?

Tags: prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter, kube-prometheus-stack

My chart: kube-prometheus-stack-54.2.2

**I added four external nodes:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-infra
  namespace: ops-monit
  labels:
    app: external-infra
spec:
  ports:
    - name: metrics
      port: 9100
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9100

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-infra
  namespace: ops-monit
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.128.0.13
    - ip: 10.128.0.4
    - ip: 10.128.0.7
    - ip: 10.128.0.10
    ports:
      - name: metrics
        port: 9100
        protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: external-infra
  namespace: ops-monit
  labels:
    app: external-infra
spec:
  endpoints:
    - port: metrics
      interval: 10s
      path: /metrics
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: external-infra
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - ops-monit
```

**Then I checked that the service sees the endpoints:**

```
$ kubectl describe ep external-infra

Name:         external-infra
Namespace:    ops-monit
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.128.0.13,10.128.0.4,10.128.0.7,10.128.0.10
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    metrics  9100  TCP
Events:  <none>


$ kubectl describe svc external-infra

Name:              external-infra
Namespace:         ops-monit
Labels:            app=external-infra
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          <none>
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.120.203.151
IPs:               10.120.203.151
Port:              metrics  9100/TCP
TargetPort:        9100/TCP
Endpoints:         10.128.0.13:9100,10.128.0.4:9100,10.128.0.7:9100 + 1 more...
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

**But Prometheus still doesn’t see my nodes:**
[image]

What is my mistake?

The Stack requires writing more text because there is more code than text. I hope the Stackoverflow will accept this text and allow me to create this question.

Comment: Prometheus Operator v0.65.x adds a [`ScrapeConfig`](https://prometheus-operator.dev/docs/user-guides/scrapeconfig/) CRD that can (also) be used to scrape external targets.

Comment: I tried your approach and it works for me. One thing you could try is `curl`'ing the Service from another Pod in the cluster to ensure that the Service is correctly accessing the remote Node Exporters `curl http://external-infra.ops-monit.svc.cluster.local:9100/metrics`

Comment: Hello  DazWilkin. Your link helped me set everything up. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! I'm pleased to hear it